# How to get value of variable assigned inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the sample code below. The variable alpha is defined inside the thread. How can I get the variable of that variable outside the thread?

```
    ...


    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        ...
        String alpha = "new value";
        ...
        ...
        }   
    }.start();
    ...
    System.out.println(alpha); // <- how to make this work?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the result in a field. Your question wasn't clear whether the the code was in a non-static or static method, so I've written an example using a `static` method and made the field `static` accordingly. If it was an instance method the field should not be `static`. It must be `volatile` so that the changes are seen in the main thread.

```
public class Main {

    private static volatile String alpha = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alpha = "new value";
            }
        }.start();

        while (alpha == null);   // We wait until the variable is non-null.
        System.out.println(alpha);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why declare static ? What would be happen if you did not declare variable static?

Comment: We're in static main is why.

Comment: @neat159 I only made it static because I was accessing from main.

Comment: If we don't declare static we would have to instantiate Main:

Main m = new Main();

Comment: ok then got it :) i thought another reason.I know that we should declare for main to access it :)

Comment: Yup and then we could access it like this

m.Alpha = "Hello World";

Although, strictly speaking it is better style to declare all non-static variables as private. And if they are private we will need setter and getters. Often it is good to use static to avoid this confusion.

Comment: `"We're in static main is why."` -- where is this stated within the main question? I would get static out of this answer unless this becomes a stated and justified requirement of the original question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The question wasn't clear, so I made a decision that the code was taking place in a `static` method. What difference does it make?

Comment: What difference? Why declare *any* variable non-static? You throw out the OOP baby with the bath-water is why. The question does not call for a static, and so neither should the answer. Remember that a newbie is asking this question and may treat your answer as gospel, and so it is far better to give him a good and robust answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The question was about accessing a variable set in a different thread, not about static/non-static variables. This example is virtually identical to the first example in the concurrency chapter in Effective Java 2nd edition. I'm sorry but that's a ridiculous reason for downvoting.

Comment: no, not ridiculous at all. You state as part of the answer that they can "store the variable in a static field" as if that were a necessary part of the solution. I have no problem with your use of a static variable in your code, but to state it in a way that will confuse the newbie into thinking that it should be declared static is wrong. Get rid of that line in the very least.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've changed the first bit. I had not meant to imply that `static` was a necessary part of the solution, and on re-reading I can see that the first sentence wasn't great before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare alpha before the thread:

```
public class Scratch {
    static String alpha;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                alpha = "new value";

            }   
        }.start();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println(alpha);

    }
}
```